# Garbled display of discussion list with raw HTML codes

Tags: 2013, discussion-board, html

We have a SharePoint 2010 site that was migrated to SharePoint 2013.  When I go to view a discussion page, each entry in the discussion is displayed as raw text with HTML codes displayed (making it very hard to read).

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem! Has anyone found a solution? It seems to happen when the user responds to the forum via Outlook. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you need to add the SharePoint site to the compatibility setting.

so go to tool in internet explore and compatibility view and add the site and you done.